# Copy-Item with remote session - how to reference remote variables?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, copy-item

I'm using `Copy-Item` with the `-ToSession` parameter to copy some local files to a remote machine. Is there a straightforward way to make the cmdlet use variables from the remote session, instead of the local one? (I imagine I can always just output the variable in the remote session and read it locally, but that's a bit unwieldy...)

Specifically, I just want to copy the files into `$env:USERPROFILE` directory.

```
$session = New-PSSession ...
Copy-Item ".\some-file.txt" -ToSession $session -Destination $env:USERPROFILE
```

Comment: Why not Invoke a command in the remote session to copy from your source to the local machine using env variables?